# Setting time limit in a game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am trying to create a clone of Freaking Math using Unity. I could not figure out how to set a timer in the top so that the game ends once the timer runs out. The countdown timer must be 2 seconds, such that when the timer runs out, the lose panel should be active.

I am new to this coding and hence couldn't figure it out. It would be great if I could get an energy bar that reduces according to the timer, so that the lose panel gets activated when the bar reaches 0.

```
public void OnFalseButtonClick()
{
    if () {
    } else {
        LosePanel.SetActive(true);
        if(currentScore>PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore")) {}
    }
```

Comment: your code is completely broken. (empty if statement, no opening/closing brackets) I would suggest you start with some basic coding lesson first

Comment: this is not the actual code. just for u guys to understand how it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Coroutines. Imho it should look something like this:

```
public void StartAnswering() {
    StartCoroutine("Timeout"); 
    canAnswer = true;
}

public Answer(bool yesOrNo) {
    if(canAnswer) {
        //Handle yes or no logic
    }
    else {
        //Answered after timeout! 
    }
}

private IEnumerator Timeout() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    canAnswer = false;
}
```